# What's inside the perinuclear space?

Tags: cell-biology, terminology, cell-membrane

The cell proper contains the cytoplasm in general and the cytosol in particular when referring to the fluid/gel without notable organelle.

Once we move inside the nucleus there is the nucleoplasm and the nucleosol.

My question is in the intervening void of the perinuclear space (between the inner and outer membrane of the nuclear envelope) what if any is the terminology used to refer to the internal chemistry in that space - and what is known about it's makeup?

Comment: The [outer nuclear membrane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_envelope#Outer_membrane) is connected to the endoplasmatic reticulum (ER), so the perinuclear space will share some characteristics with the ER as well. However, there are bound to be specific differences as well, which I don't know about.

Comment: Interesting so the perinucllear space could almost be thought of as the innermost sack of the endoplasmic reticulum.